# Disable "history.go(-1)" on certain pages

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to disable `history.go(-1)` on certain pages.
I'm wondering if there is a way to clean up the Javascript's `history` object. Any ideas?
`history.go()` seems to not be functioning too well on certain browsers such as IE. Is that true? Any solution for that?

Comment: What are you achieving my disabling this? The user can just click the back button

Comment: I have a <iframe> inside a html page. There is a button in the html page that backward-navigates the content inside the iframe, but I don't what that button to work on the landing page. For example, if originally you have Google open in the browser, and you go to my site by entering the url of my page directly to the address bar. I don't want the button to work at this point because the browser will navigate back to Google. I want the user to stay on my site.

Comment: Are the Devil or something? If the user doesn't want to be on your site, don't try and force them to be!

Comment: @user359996 haha. Sorry I didn't explain myself clearly. It's actually a web app optimized for iPhone. I need to showcase it on desktop by putting an iframe on top of an iPhone image. I need to simulate the back button of Safari mobile browser on the bottom of the screen to provide the iPhone experience. My boss doesn't want the back button to work on the landing page.I know it's stupid but what can I do. lol.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can over-write the `go` method, but it doesn't get you much

```
history.go = function(){};
```

This will disable all uses of `history.go`, and not just when you pass a `-1`.

And as others have pointed out - this doesn't stop the user from using the Back button on their browser.

Answer (score 6):

The best you can do to "disable" history is to open your page in a new window, which will have no history. Pages opened in a new window don't have a back button enabled and history.go(-1) will not do anything

Short of that, there is nothing you would (or should) be able to do.

Revised to make an implication explicit. I thought I was being clear, but apparently I was not.

Comment: Ctrl-H opens history in any window

Comment: @m.edmondson: I'm aware of that, but pages opened in a new window don't have a back button enabled and history.go(-1) will not do anything.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot override this browser behavior. If you could there would be mayhem as malware would try to take over everyone's history.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to disable the browsers BACK button this is simply not possible.  Would you like it if websites could mess around with your browsers functionality?

Comment: It is possible to make it very difficult for users to go back, if they have JavaScript enabled. I've used some sites like this. And I hate it when they do that.

Comment: Yea I know what you mean.  Usually clicking back a couple of times quickly gets what you want.  I'm guessing theres an intermediate page that returns the appropriate javascript and or HTTP code to forward the browser on

Answer (score 0):

You've got two options.

1. Load pages with post request, this will prevent users from using back-button as you can trap the reload on server-side. (You need to wrap all hyperlinks with js though, so a bit of work, and the solution is quite ugly.)
2. Use DOM to load content into page. History won't be able to backtrack it. (or am i wrong here :-| )
3. describe your problem more clearly, there's probably better solutions for where you need to go.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your shared page header:

```
<body onLoad="history.forward()">
```

It will always force the user to the most recent page they've visited on your website.

Answer (score 0):

This is ugly, but might work:

```
$(document).load(function(){   
   document.location.href = document.location.href + "#";   
   setInterval(function(){   
      if (window.location.hash != '#')   
         document.location.href = document.location.href + "#";   
   }, 100);   
});
```

ugh!

Answer (score 0):

Desmond,

*My boss doesn't want the back button to work on the landing page.I know it's stupid but what can I do.*

What about using default page, (index.php or whatever) to point forward.

index.php:

```
header('location:start.html');
//or likewise with js,
document.location = 'start.html';
```

start.html:

```
my real start
```

as user hits the back-button, the index.php will redo the forwarding.

regards,

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the responses. After two days of juggling, I came up this solution, for now.
I use PHP to output a class to the body tag if it's the current page is the front page. Something like

```
<body class='front'>
```

and then use jQuery to enable/disable "history.go(X)" on the fly.

```
$(document).ready(){
    if($('body.front').length>0){
        $('#backbutton').click(function(){ window.history.back(); }); 
    }else{
        $('#backbutton').unbind('click');
    }
}
```

In fact the project that I was working on require the site inside an iframe to disable the element that triggers the back button of the parent window. The js becomes:

```
var backbutton=parent.window.getElementById('#backbutton');
$(document).ready(){
    if($('body.front').length>0){
        $(backbutton).click(function(){ window.history.back(); }); 
    }else{
        $(backbutton).unbind('click');
    }
}
```